# Don't send form data when to type no in confirm window

Tags: javascript, confirm

Type `apple` in the input whose name is `goods`,and type `9` in the input whose name is `price`,and click `submit`,now confirm window pop up,whatever your click `yes` or `no`,the data will send to `price.php`.
My expectation:
when you click `yes` ,the data will send to `price.php`, 
when you click `no` ,the data will not send to `price.php`,what's wrong for my js?

```js
ob = document.getElementById("submit");
function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("price").value < 10){
        var flag = window.confirm(" are your sure the price is less than 10 ?");
        if(flag){
            return true;
        }else{
            exit;
         }
    }
}
ob.addEventListener("click",check,false);
```

```html
<form action="price.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>goods</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="goods"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>price</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The `price.php` is simple.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

The `exit` below can't  prevent form data from sending to `price.php`.

```
        if(flag){
            return true;
        }else{
            exit;
         }
```

It is no use either to change  `exit;` into `return false;`.
It is no use either to change js into below.

```
ob = document.getElementById("submit");
function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("price").value < 10){
        var flag = window.confirm(" are your sure the price is less than 10 ?");
        if(flag){
            return true;
        }else{
            exit;
         }
    }
}
ob.addEventListener("submit",check,false);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The traditional way is same as `The KNVB` did,the key point is `<form action="price.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">` ,to bind form's attribute `onsubmit` with function `check`.

DOM0 level event way,almost the same like the traditional way.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="price.php" method="post" id="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>goods</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="goods"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <script>
            var ob = document.getElementById('submit');            
            ob.onclick =function(){
                if(document.getElementById("price").value < 10){
                    var flag = window.confirm(" are your sure the price is less than 10 ?");
                    if(flag){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                     }
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What OP expect is the DOM2 level event way.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="price.php" method="post" id="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>goods</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="goods"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <script>
            var ob = document.getElementById('submit');  
            function check(event){
                console.log(ob.type);
                if(document.getElementById("price").value < 10){
                    var flag = window.confirm(" are your sure the price is less than 10 ?");
                    if(flag){
                        ob.submit();
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                     }
                }
           } 
           ob.addEventListener("click",check);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key points in `DOM2 level event way` are:

1.when flag is true

```
if(flag){
    ob.submit();
    return true;
 }
```

2.when flag is false

```
else{
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="price.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>goods</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="goods"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <script>
            function check()
            {
                if(document.getElementById("price").value < 10){
                    var flag = window.confirm(" are your sure the price is less than 10 ?");
                    if(flag){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                     }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tested it on Edge, IE11, Firefox, chrome browser, it works.

I found another solution:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="price.php" method="post" id="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>goods</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="goods"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>price</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <script>
            var ob = document.getElementById('form');  
            function check(event){
                if(document.getElementById("price").value < 10){
                    var flag = window.confirm(" are your sure the price is less than 10 ?");
                    if(flag){
                        ob.submit();
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                     }
                }
           } 
           ob.addEventListener("submit",check);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your js code works fine ,why my js code can't work as expected?

Comment: His code works fine because form tag has attribute onsubmit="return check()". If false is returned it prevents submission.

Comment: You do not associate the "onsubmit" event with the validation function.

Comment: `ob.addEventListener("onsubmit",check,false); `  can't work in my js code.

Comment: variable ob is submit button object, you should add on submit event listener to the form object not the submit button object, however, I haven't tried it before, I cannot guarantee it works as you want .

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things about the code:

1. `exit` - I've never seen before - is it javascript?
2. `document.getElementById('price').value` - returns a string - you should parse it (to a number) before comparing.
3. Use `onsubmit=""` attribute of the form - return `true` to allow form submission, `false` to block submission.
4. `window.confirm` already returns a boolean, just return that (instead of `if` statement).

Here's a bare-bones example:

```js
function validate() {
  const price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').value)
  if (price < 10) {
    return window.confirm("Are your sure the price is less than 10 ?")
  }
  return true // <- otherwise allow form submission
}
```

```html
<form action="price.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="price" name="price">
  <input type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
```

Also, in general, try to condense your problem to the minimum code required to reproduce an issue.